# How would I format python code using python?

Tags: python

Let's say I've got this code in python:

`total=0for i in range(100):print(i)if i > 50:total=total+i`

How would I make an algorithm in python to format this python code into the code below:

```
total=0
for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    if i > 50:
        total=total+i
```

Assume that everything is nested under each other, such that another statement would be assumed to be inside the `if` block.

Comment: That is not actually python code. It is a string that could be formatted as python code.

Comment: How do you determine the indent of the if statement? It also works outside the for loop.

Comment: @MechanicPig oops i didn't mention that! i've changed the question. So it is assumed that everything is nested, and that the if loop is in the for loop, and if there was another statement that would be in the if loop.

Comment: @JohnColeman i know

Comment: This is not possible in general. Consider `a=bc=d`, which could be just one line, or two lines`a=b` and `c=d`, and countless other examples are possible, even without getting started with indentation.

Comment: Probably would be better if you illustrate the problem you're trying to solve with _formatting one liners._. If the community understands the big picture, they can definitely suggest an alternate approach instead of _formatting one liners._

Comment: @tobias_k yes, but what im doing is just putting some formatting, and the errors in the lines i could correct later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was quite a fun exercise! I'm running out of juice so just posting this as is. It works on your example but probably not much for anything more complex.

```
code_block = "total=0for i in range(100):print(i)if i > 50:total=total+iprint('finished')"
code_block_b = "def okay() {print('ff')while True:print('blbl')break}"

line_break_before = ['for', 'while', 'if', 'print', 'break', '}']
line_break_after = [':', '{']
indent_chars = [':', '{']
unindent_chars = ['}']

# Add line breaks before keywords
for kw in line_break_before:
    kw_indexes = [idx for idx in range(len(code_block)) if code_block[idx:idx + len(kw)] == kw]
    for kw_idx in kw_indexes[::-1]:
        code_block = code_block[:kw_idx] + '\n' + code_block[kw_idx:]

# Add line breaks after other keywords if not present already
for kw in line_break_after:
    kw_indexes = [idx for idx in range(len(code_block)) if code_block[idx:idx + len(kw)] == kw]
    for kw_idx in kw_indexes[::-1]:
        if code_block[kw_idx + 1: kw_idx + 2] != '\n':
            code_block = code_block[:kw_idx + 1] + '\n' + code_block[kw_idx + 1:]

# Add indentation
indent = 0
formatted_code_lines = []
for line in code_block.split('\n'):
    if line[-1] in unindent_chars:
        indent = 0
    formatted_code_lines.append(' ' * indent)
    if line[-1] in indent_chars:
        indent += 4
    formatted_code_lines.append(line + '\n')

code_block = ''.join(formatted_code_lines)

print(code_block)
```

The basic premise for formatting is based around keywords. There are keys that require a line break before, and keys that require a line break after them. After that, the indentation was counted +4 spaces for every line after each `:` symbol. I tested some formatting with braces too in `code_block_b`.

Output a

```
total=0
for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    if i > 50:
        total=total+i
```

Output b

```
def okay() {
    print('ff')
    while True:
        print('blbl')
        break
}
```

Comment: Curly braces? `from __future__ import braces`